# osx audio player with selectable soundcard output?

Tags: macosx, playback

hi, i need to route the audio out of different software (e.g. browser, audio player) through different channels of my soundcard (rme babyface). but i can't find suitable audio players, they all seem to use ch 1+2 with no option to select other playback channels. which audio player for OSX supports multi channel soundcards?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested out using Cycling 74's [Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/)? Not exactly what you're asking for, but it might provide a useful (free) solution for you.

Comment: Could also whip up a quick little customised audio router in Max... if you want to be more of a nerd about it.

Comment: soundflower does the job pretty well, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You might try opening the Audio/MIDI setup in the Applications->Utilities folder. In the audio window, click on the Babyface, and click the "Speaker Configuration" button. It should allow you to select a channel of the interface for the L/R outputs from the system.

Best,
~Matt